# Test code coverage with Robolectric and Maven

Tags: android, maven, code-coverage, robolectric

I have been searching internet for hours now and have not got any working solutions yet.

The question is simple: **how to get test code coverage in Android maven project using Robolectric as testing library?**

I have tried JaCoCo and Cobertura but no success. There is always some kind of error. I think my problem is that I just can't install right code coverage plugin for Maven correctly. I know there is plenty of example POM files and code snippets, but I have not got any luck there.

Robolectric is btw working correclty.

**My project dir looks like this:**

```
  | parent project
  |-- app project
  |-- test project
```

Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/) does exactly what you're looking for.

**EDIT:**

[These docs will help](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Code+Coverage+by+Unit+Tests+for+Java+Project) if you haven't found them already.

The [Android plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Android+Plugin) will also be very useful to you.

Comment: Thanks! Got things working, finally. But report raw files are going into test project instead of app project, and sonar can't find them there. So, I have to manually copy needed files from test to app project. Not the nicest way, but works!

Comment: Glad it works for you! I added a link to the official docs and hopefully that helps you out more.